Missing Extra objects in saved file, not missing when opening a scratch blank file
I am having this issue in blender 4.3, I installed the BoltFactory Add on, enabled it and also install / enabled the add extra mesh one, however, when I try to create a bolt, I can't if I am working in a previously saved file, however, if I create a new general file, the add on works perfectly.
Any ideas of what am I doing wrong here?


Nevermind, I figured out what was the problem... solved in the panel that opens with "n" - Tool - tick the addons that were missing

